# Render a CVPixelBuffer to an NSView (macOS)

Tags: macos, opengl, render, core-image, cvpixelbuffer

I have a `CVPixelBuffer` that I'm trying to efficiently draw on screen.

The not-efficient way of turning into an `NSImage` works but is very slow, dropping about 40% of my frames.

Therefore, I've tried rendering it on-screen using `CIContext`'s `drawImage:inRect:fromRect`. The `CIContext` was initialized with a `NSOpenGLContext` who's view was set to my VC's view. When I have a new image, I call the `drawImage` method which doesn't spit out any errors... but doesn't display anything on screen either (it did log errors when my contexts were not correctly setup).

I've tried to find an example of how this is done on MacOS, but everything seems to be for iOS nowadays.

EDIT:

Here's some of the code I am using. I've left out irrelevant sections

On `viewDidLoad` I init the GL and CI contexts

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute pixelFormatAttr[] = {
  kCGLPFAAllRenderers, 0
};
NSOpenGLPixelFormat *glPixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes: pixelFormatAttr];
NSOpenGLContext *glContext = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:glPixelFormat shareContext:nil];
glContext.view = self.view;

self.ciContext = [CIContext contextWithCGLContext:glContext.CGLContextObj pixelFormat:glPixelFormat.CGLPixelFormatObj colorSpace:nil options:nil];
```

Then, when a new frame is ready, I do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [vc.ciContext drawImage:ciImage inRect:vc.view.bounds fromRect:ciImage.extent];
        vc.isRendering = NO;
});
```

I am not sure I'm calling draw in the right place, but I can't seem to find out where is this supposed to go.

Comment: Hello ,and welcome to SO. Before your are getting your question marked to be closed, I suggest you to rewrite it because in its current state it doesn't fit into SO Q&A format. Please add some actual code of yours depicting a specific problem.

Comment: I've added the used code... but it's not much.

Comment: I'm not very skilled with OSX, but I think you must set the gl-context as current (use  `[glContext makeCurrentContext];`. And don't forget to swap buffers ( `[glContext flushBuffer];`) after your rendering.

Comment: There's logic to that, but it doesn't work though (tried it already). I did have a little breakthrough by moving all of that code inside an NSOpenGLView and calling the `drawImage:` method in it's `drawRect:` method... and calling a `glFlush()` at the end. However, the image was displayed in the top right quad of the screen and really blurry. The positioning reminds me of how the GL renderer on iOS works... so I do have an idea on how to fix that.

Comment: It seems to me you're mixing OpenGL and OpenGL-ES (that "CI context"). There is plenty of info at [Apple Developers site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH207-TP9)

Comment: I got my info from Apple’s documentation. The gist of it is that `CIContext`’s `drawImage:` only works with contexts made from `CGLContext` or a `CGContext`. The `glFlush()` is a standard OpenGL call, which admittedly didn’t have a place in my setup per se... anyway, if I don’t manage to find a simple way of rendering this through a `CIContext`, I’ll go about making a pure OpenGL implementation and be done with it.

Comment: CGLContext _is_ Cocoa. AGLContext is Carbon

Answer (score 2):

If the `CVPixelBuffer` has the [`kCVPixelBufferIOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibilityKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/kcvpixelbufferiosurfacecoreanimationcompatibilitykey) attribute, the backing [`IOSurface`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iosurface) (retrieved via [`CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456690-cvpixelbuffergetiosurface)) can be passed directly to the [`contents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410773-contents) property of a `CALayer`.

This is probably the most efficient way to display a `CVPixelBuffer`.

Comment: That’s interesting, I’ll have a look as soon as possible to validate if this works or not. This is quite old, but I remember finding a solution by going totally OpenGL (writing a renderer with a custom shader and all that) - worked flawlessly and very fast, but there was a lot of code to it.